# how does Google Maps render large image data?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new in an organization that has an application that renders large tiled images in a web app.  Like Google Maps, it has to zoom and pan the views, but unlike Google Maps, it suffers from performance problems.

Is there a general or technical discussion somewhere about the architecture and design of the Google Maps rendering engine?  I'd love to get some ideas from how Google Maps is implemented.

Cheers!

Comment: A couple of starting points:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service

http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WMS

I'm unsure as to the specifics of Google's implementation but some of the basic principles and examples are there.